# Is there any research that tracks fragmentation and drop rates of UDP packets based on size?

Tags: udp, transport-protocol, packet-loss

I'm designing a P2P system. I need to decide an ideal packet size that maximizes the efficiency of my system. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35697810/1031791) answer claims a 508 bytes is the maximum safe size, but I believe larger packets should also have low drop rates in modern equipment. I wonder what is a reasonable size in practice, today. Is there any research tracking drop and fragmentation rates across multiple routes in different places based on packet size?

Comment: Regardless of size, you _will_ lose UDP datagrams because UDP is connectionless with no guarantees. You either need to build tracking and resending into your application, or you need to use a protocol, e.g. TCP, that provides guaranteed delivery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general rule - some networks pass packets up to the over-standard-Ethernet MTU (1500 bytes), some don't. 508 bytes for UDP payload is derived from the minimum MTU of 576 bytes and looks plausible - but is not efficient.

The ideal way to deal with this - for maximum efficiency - is to make your system support variable datagram sizes and use *path MTU discovery* (PMTUD) to select the optimal size. It's fairly simple really.